# How to Test a lodash's debounce function using Jest in react native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, jestjs, lodash

I'm not able to test a method which contains a debounce function using jest in my react native component. Can someone help me with this?

The below code is what I tried to test my debounce function in jest but it did not work.

```
jest.mock('lodash/debounce', () => jest.fn(fn => fn));

  it('should test debounce function', () => {
    debounce.mockClear();
    expect(debounce).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

The below snippet is my method which contains lodash's debounce function which I'm trying to test.

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

  private getSearchConnections = debounce(() => {
    this.props.searchConnections(this.state.query, 1, false);
    }, 100
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 approaches, the first one is the one you are trying to do, to test delegation.
You could do more assertions like

```js
expect(debounce).toHaveBeenCallWith(yourFn);
```

The second one you could try is to use fake timer.

```js
it('msg', () => {
  jest.useFakeTimer();

  try {
    getSearchConnections();
    getSearchCOnnections();

    jest.advanceTimerByTime(100);

    expect(searchConnections).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  } finally {
    jest.useRealTimer();
  }
});
```

---

Some minor detail, usually in the message, we just describe how the class should behave instead of how the test should test, like `it should delegate to debounce` or `it should debounce call to some API`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. none of the code inside debounced function is executed

Comment: Please give more details, preferably a reproducible repo/code, or some pseudocode at least.

Answer (score 2):

debounce has a `flush` method you can call to immediate invoke it https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

```
getSearchConnections();
getSearchConnections.flush();

expect(searchConnections).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```